# The adjoint of $T_a: L^2 (\mathbb R^d) \to L^2 (\mathbb R^d), u \mapsto a * u$

Tags: functional-analysis, banach-spaces, lp-spaces, convolution, adjoint-operators

Let $a \in L^1 (\mathbb R^d)$ be a fixed function. Consider a linear operator
$$
T_a: L^2 (\mathbb R^d) \to L^2 (\mathbb R^d), u \mapsto a * u.
$$

By Young's inequality, $\|a*u\|_2 \le \|a\|_1 \|u\|_2$ for all $u \in L^2 (\mathbb R^d)$. Then $T_a$ is bounded. I'm trying to find the adjoint $T_a^*$ of $T_a$. Could you check if my reasoning is fine?

---

For $u, w \in L^2 (\mathbb R^d)$, we have $\langle T_a^* u, w \rangle = \langle u, T_a w \rangle$ and thus $\int (T_a^* u) w = \int u (T_a w)$. On the other hand,
$$
\int u (T_a w) = \int u (a*w) = \int w(\check a *u),
$$
where $\check a (x) := a(-x)$ for all $x \in \mathbb R^d$. It follows that $T_a^* u = \check a *u$.

Comment: Fine if you are considering spaces of functions with real values (if complex values, some conjugation signs are missing).

Comment: @AnneBauval Thank you so much for your verification! I indeed work with real-valued functions.